# Backbone.js Views: I need to undelegate only one event on a View

Tags: events, backbone.js, view, backbone-views

I have a Backbone.View which has the following events:

```
...

events : {
    "click .text1" : "doSomething",
    "click .text2" : "doAnotherThing",
},

...
```

I need to undelegate the second event. I know you can use this.undelegateEvents(); but it undelegates all the events on the view. I need to undelegate only one event.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents):

> **delegateEvents** `delegateEvents([events])`
>
> Uses jQuery's `on` function to provide declarative callbacks for DOM events within a view.
>   [...]
>   When **delegateEvents** is run again, perhaps with a different `events` hash, all callbacks are removed and delegated afresh — useful for views which need to behave differently when in different modes.

Note two things:

1. You can pass an `events` object to `delegateEvents`, it will use `this.events` by default but you can use different events if you want to.
2. Calling `delegateEvents` will, more or less, call `undelegateEvents` before binding the new ones.

Putting those together gives us:

```
this.delegateEvents(
    _(this.events).omit('click .text2')
);
```

as an easy way to remove the single event handler that you want to get rid of. BTW, [`_.omit`](http://underscorejs.org/#omit) just gives you a copy of an object with certain keys left out so `_(this.events).omit('click .text2')` can be used to get the event bindings you're interested in without altering `this.events` (which is attached to the prototype and so shared by all current and future instances of your view).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/T6ncT/

Answer (score 0):

From the backbone docs:

> A single-event version of **delegateEvents** is available as `delegate`. In
>   fact, **delegateEvents** is simply a multi-event wrapper around `delegate`.
>   A counterpart to `undelegateEvents` is available as `undelegate`.

The function from the source code is:

```
undelegate: function(eventName, selector, listener) {
  this.$el.off(eventName + '.delegateEvents' + this.cid, selector, listener);
  return this;
}
```

So call `this.undelegate("click",".text2")`.